# Smart Mailbox is suddenly empty

Tags: email, smart-folders

I created a Smart Mailbox this morning. I programmed it to hold all mail relating to my property purchase. This was successful. i checked it several times and it was full of all the relevant mail.

This evening I went into the mailbox to find a back-dated mail, and it was empty. There is no mail at all. There is a message reading 'No Messages Selected'.

I am seriously freaking out! Help me!

Comment: If you right click and select Edit Smart box, does the menu looks the way it should (as you programed it)

Answer (score 2):

You may have disabled Spotlight index searching which also affects Mail.

To enable index search again, go to Settings > Spotlight > Privacy tab > Remove your hard disk from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Slect the smart mailbox in the sidebar and choose "Edit Smart Mailbox" and look at what the conditions are. They may be a date constraint or it may be limited to a certain mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not panic.

The smart box only collects the emails (copy) per your specifications.

If the are not longer in your Smart box, they are still in your Mailboxes (or Archive)

Right Click on the Smart box and double check what is it supposed to do.

Meanwhile you can use the search to find your originals in the appropriate mail box.